# Do I flag a question as spam, or vote to close it as spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

Sometimes spamy questions are voted to be closed like

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because spam

Do I flag a question as spam, or vote to close it as spam?

Comment: Main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96007/vote-to-close-or-flag-as-spam-or-both

Comment: Always flag spam, but it doesn't hurt to VTC spam, as well as flag it. Sometimes spam avoids the necessary number of flags to auto-delete.

Comment: "You should always flag spam." - Thanks for the link, @AlexanderO'Mara. I did look for duplicates. Good to know that the answer from 2011 is still valid.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Flag it as spam. It's the very first option you see in the flag dialog. It is a special option that will not only cause a question to be automatically deleted when enough flags accumulate, but also train the anti-spam system to block future attempts. Close votes do not have this effect.

If you see someone voting to close for such a reason, remind them to *flag* the question instead. If you vote to close *instead* of flagging, then you're really allowing the question to live by not feeding it enough flags to be auto-deleted. Questions with 4 or 5 active spam flags that stick around for hours or days are often the result of this negligence. Not only that, but you're also allowing the spammer to continue spamming both on this site and elsewhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Once you've flagged the question as spam, you can vote to close it to ensure that it remains closed if it turns out *not* to be spam, but if you're confident that the post *is* spam then you're really just wasting a close vote there.

Comment: What do you think of using VTC to kick a spam question in the review queue, when spam has managed to live longer than usual?

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: I guess it wouldn't hurt to have more eyeballs on the question in that case.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You could always bring it to a chat room.  I belong to the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and one of the things we do is watch for and get rid of spam.  If you suspect spam or want to get eyes on it you can always hop in the room.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, I'm a regular there.